# Oracle regular expression having a hyphen doesn't give same result on Windows as on Unix

Tags: regex, oracle, sqlplus

I have the following query with a regular expression:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE ('TEST 3304 V2', '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|;.:<>?,./]', ' ') as REG 
from dual;
```

When executed via SQL*Plus on a **Windows** machine it returns the following:

```
SQL>  select REGEXP_REPLACE ('TEST 3304 V2', '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|;.:<>?,./]', ' ') as REG from dual;

REG
------------
TEST 3304 V2
```

On a **SunOS** machine I get a different result:

```
SQL>  select REGEXP_REPLACE ('TEST 3304 V2', '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|;.:<>?,./]', ' ') as REG from dual;

REG
------------
TEST      V
```

These queries were run against the same Oracle server. Is there any reason for that difference in the output?

**SQL*Plus version on Windows:**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mar. Oct. 14 15:36:35 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

**SQL*Plus version on Unix:**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 14 16:01:26 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Comment: Use `-` at the first or at the last in your char class if you don't want it to act like a range operator..

Comment: like this [-`~!@#$%^&*()_+={}|;.:<>?,./]

Comment: Still odd that the behaviour is different though. If the two instances are exactly the same version and patch level, are the character sets different, perhaps?

Comment: @AlexPoole I added the version of Oracle and SQL*Plus on both machines.. How can I check the character sets?

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks your solution worked for me, but I'd still like to know what makes the difference between the two ?

Comment: @MajidL: The `-` if in the middle may be interpreted as character range. It usually lost its meaning when it is near the opening `[` or closing `]` of a character class

Comment: @MajidL - since it's the Window's client that's not seeing the numbers as part of the range (under [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), `+-=` is the range of all characters from chr(43) to chr(61), which includes digits), what is [NLS_LANG set to](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html) in that environment?

Comment: I get the same on SUSE as well as Windows from 11.2.0.1.0 to 11.2.0.3.5 and 12.1.0.1.0 ... I suspect that everyone's correct and this is just being interpreted as a character range. This feels like a bug with your Windows client and some non-obvious regex parsing by Oracle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Avinash Raj said in comments, the hyphen in your regular expression pattern is being interpreted as a range. The behaviour seems to be dependent on the sorting algorithm being used by the two clients, based on the NLS_LANG environment variable, which influences the NLS_SORT value.

With `NLS_LANG=ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8ISO8859P1`:

```
SQL> select REGEXP_REPLACE ('TEST 3304 V2', '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|;.:<>?,./]', ' ') as REG from dual;

REG
------------
TEST      V

SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_SORT';

VALUE
----------
BINARY
```

Going out on a limb as your profile says you're in Morocco, with `NLS_LANG="ARABIC_MOROCCO.AR8MSWIN1256"`:

```
SQL> select REGEXP_REPLACE ('TEST 3304 V2', '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|;.:<>?,./]', ' ') as REG from dual;

REG
------------
TEST 3304 V2

SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_SORT';

VALUE
----------
ARABIC
```

The reason is that the pattern segment `+-=` is treated as a range covering all characters from `+` to `=`. In the ISO8859-1 and [Windows 1252 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) that is characters 43 to 61, and all the numeric digits fall within that range - zero is 48 for example - are within that range, so the regex replaces them. That is also true in the [Windows 1256 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256). (And anything based on ASCII).

But your NLS_LANG is also implicitly changing the sort order, and it's switch from BINARY to ARABIC sorting that changes the behaviour. You can see that within a single session; with `NLS_LANG=ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8ISO8859P1`:

```
SQL> select REGEXP_REPLACE ('TEST 3304 V2', '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|;.:<>?,./]', ' ') as REG from dual;

REG
------------
TEST      V

SQL> alter session set NLS_SORT=ARABIC;

Session altered.

SQL> select REGEXP_REPLACE ('TEST 3304 V2', '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|;.:<>?,./]', ' ') as REG from dual;

REG
------------
TEST 3304 V2
```

You can also tell that it is a range issue by slightly modifying the range; changing `+-=` to `+-3` so higher digits are not included, but leaving everything else the same:

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY;

Session altered.

SQL> select REGEXP_REPLACE ('TEST 3304 V2', '[`~!@#$%^&*()_+-3{}|;.:<>?,./]', ' ') as REG from dual;

REG
------------
TEST    4 V
```

[Read more about linguistic sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#i1005958).

Relying on NLS settings is always risky though, so it's better to avoid the range issue entirely by changing the pattern to have the hyphen at the beginning or end, which stops it being seen as a range at all; again as Avinash Raj suggested.

Comment: What does that mean 'change the sort order' ? Ascii codes aren't ascii ? How about `[` no more class ?

Comment: I speculate this is not the problem. `-` the range operator is a metachar inside classes, as such it is escapable, which he can't seem to do.

Comment: @sln - maybe but this isn't a class? You can [read more about linguistic sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#i1005958); BINARY sorts based on the "numeric values of the characters defined by the character encoding scheme", which ARABIC (or any language-based sort) sorts based on "numeric values that reflect each character's proper linguistic order". So with ARABIC, the `+-=` range just happens to not include the digits, because of how that scheme is sorted.

Comment: @sln - I added a very slightly modified query to show that it is a range issue; changing `=` to `3` knocks out the occurrences of 2 and 3, but now leaves 4 behind.

Comment: @sln - I didn't really mean that this isn't a class... of course it's a character class. But at least [according to this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), a hyphen is a metacharacter inside a character class, but isn't escapable; it has to come first or last. But I suspect you know rather more about regex than I do, I'm just looking at what Oracle is doing really...

Comment: Not true, the backslash is a metacharacter, the primary one in classes. It introduces sequence constructs as well as escaping metachars, specifically when a dash `-` and can be anywhere in the class when escaped. That's why the problem lies elsewhere. More likely an extreme bug in their engine.

Comment: My reading of the previous link and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) is that "backslash escapes are not allowed" in POSIX, and therefore Oracle's implementation. I don't understand this area enough to argue about it though.

Comment: Ok, don't know Oracle's implementation. If its POSIX, all bets are off I guess.