# Regular Expression with Hyphen giving different results

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to replace all the characters that are not

In the range a-z

In the range A-Z

Spaces

Hyphen

Underscore

Opening (

Closing )

I arrived at this RegEx

```
[^0-9A-Za-z\-\(\)]
```

When i test this on the String (Hi-There) at https://www.regex101.com/ i get the result (Hi-There)

When i use the same expression in a Oracle Query using

```
SELECT regexp_replace('(Hi-There)','[^0-9A-Za-z\-\(\)]', '')  FROM dual
```

I get only (HiThere) with the missing hyphen.

What is going wrong?

Comment: [Oracle regular expression having a hyphen doesn't give same result on Windows as on Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26363671/458741) is a more complicated version of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try put it at the end:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('(Hi-There)','[^0-9A-Za-z\(\)\-]', '')  FROM dual
```

Also, as @DavidFaber and @hwnd said, you don't need to escape `()` either `-` so:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('(Hi-There)','[^0-9A-Za-z()-]', '')  FROM dual
```

Will be right.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me, but I'd love to hear *why* it works.

Comment: i'm cusious too, and i really don't know why this happens :)

Comment: it's because `-` act like a range operator between \ and \. So it would match ony the \ not `-` . You may check this with `[\-\]` . This would match only \ not hyphen.

Comment: Looks like Oracle's regex implementation is broken. When the hyphen is escaped it shouldn't be treated as a range indicator.

Comment: I think oracle uses BRE. Same happens with grep `echo 'foo-\' | grep -o '[\]'`

Comment: Oracle uses POSIX ERE. Also the `-` need not be escaped if it falls at the end (or the beginning!) of the character class.

Comment: aahh, i see. I try it, and it really don't need to be escaped in this case. Thanks @DavidFaber

Comment: I'd be surprised if the parentheses need to be escaped, either, since they're in a character class.

Comment: You could write it as `[^a-zA-Z0-9()-]`